# How to find and replace only items appearing between square brackets with sed?

Tags: replace, sed

I am using `sed` to find and replace some items in a file, like this:

```
    sed -i "s/$a/$b/g" ./file.txt
```

I need to limit this find and replace to only when the matching text is somewhere between square brackets, e.g.:

```
The sheep lived in the barn.
One day, [the sheep ate some] grass.
The [sheep] found a nice place to sleep under the tree.
Afterwards, [the sheep ate apples under] the tree [near the barn].
The sheep [enjoyed the theme] of the movie.
```

Suppose `$a` were set to "the" and `$b` set to "B", the output would look like this:

```
The sheep lived in the barn.
One day, [B sheep ate some] grass.
The [sheep] found a nice place to sleep under the tree.
Afterwards, [B sheep ate apples under] the tree [near B barn].
The sheep [enjoyed B theme] of the movie.
```

- The opening and closing square brackets always appear on the same lines.

How can I find and replace only those items which appear somewhere between square brackets with `sed`?

Comment: Why with `sed`, specifically? (I ask because I think it's easier with Perl. In Perl 5.14 or higher, you could write `perl -p -i -e 's{\[.*?\]}{$& =~ s/the/B/gr}ge' ./file.txt`.)

Comment: Ruakh, I've been looking for something like that. Do you have a link to more details? I got it to work for my use case (escaping all underscores in LaTex \textcite{} commands) but I'd love to more formally learn about it: I don't even know what that form of two step searching is called...

Answer (score 5):

You can try this ,

```
sed -i.bak -r "s#(\[[^]]*)$a( [^[]*\])#\1$b\2#g" ./file.txt
```